# Is anyone else NOT getting the purchaseToken every time for Android in-app-billing Subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

We have an Android subscription product.  We are only getting the purchaseToken on new subscriptions 50% of the time.  We need this token from Google to track subscription renewals from the server.  Is anyone else experiencing this problem?  We have tried over the last month to find someone at Google who can speak to this, without success.  There does not appear to be a work around to get the purchaseToken from another venue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It would be great if someone has some sample code on how to query Google for the purchase token if it does not arrive with the success indicator.  That way I could request the token immediately after failure.